# Python Loop Time Calculation by Month

Tags: python, loops, debugging, time

I am creating a python program to print two numbers. Both numbers are integers with a yyyymm format. The second number is 11 months apart from the first one. I am trying to loop through a time range to print them. For example, here is the ideal result:

```
201101 201112
201102 201201
201103 201202
201104 201203
...
201312 201411
```

Currently I have a program as follows:

```
import time
def to_month(yyyymm):
    y, m = int(yyyymm[:4]), int(yyyymm[4:])
    return y * 12 + m

def iter_months(start, end):
    for month in range(to_month(start), to_month(end) + 1):
        y, m = divmod(month-1, 12)  
        yield y, m + 1              

for y, m in iter_months('201101', '201312'):
    start = ("%d%02d" % (y, m))
    end = int((datetime.datetime.strptime(str(start), '%Y%m') + relativedelta(month=+11)).strftime('%Y%m'))
    print start, end
```

However it is not working properly as you can see in the result below. The month in the second column is fixed.

```
201101 201111
201102 201111
201103 201111
201104 201111
201105 201111
201106 201111
201107 201111
201108 201111
201109 201111
201110 201111
201111 201111
201112 201111
201201 201211
201202 201211
201203 201211
201204 201211
201205 201211
201206 201211
201207 201211
201208 201211
201209 201211
201210 201211
201211 201211
201212 201211
201301 201311
201302 201311
201303 201311
201304 201311
201305 201311
201306 201311
201307 201311
201308 201311
201309 201311
201310 201311
201311 201311
201312 201311
```

I cannot figure out what is wrong... Since when I am running the relativedelta function alone, it works perfectly well.

Can someone help here? Thanks in advance.

***EDIT:***
I found my bug in the program. It should be relativedelta(month**s**=+11)). I missed the 's' previously.

Comment: is there a reason you are not using `datetime.timedelta`?? Unless it is forbidden in your project I suggest you look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta

Comment: @Reedinationer I am looking for months apart, and it seems that timedelta doesn't have one option for month. It does have some other time units though, like seconds, hours, days, weeks, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `relativedelta` and create a function like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

def add_months(start, no_months):

    start = datetime.strptime(start, '%Y%m')

    delta = relativedelta(months=+no_months)

    end = datetime.strftime(start + delta, '%Y%m')

    return end

add_months('201101', 11)
```

The value returned is:

```
201112
```

And you can then apply this function with `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

start_dates = ['201101', '201102', '201103', '201104', '201105', '201106', '201107', '201108', '201109', '201110', '201111', '201112', '201201']

df = pd.DataFrame({'Start': start_dates})

df['End'] = df['Start'].apply(add_months, args=(11,))
```

Yields:

```
     Start     End
0   201101  201112
1   201102  201201
2   201103  201202
3   201104  201203
4   201105  201204
5   201106  201205
6   201107  201206
7   201108  201207
8   201109  201208
9   201110  201209
10  201111  201210
11  201112  201211
12  201201  201212
```

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts and time. I find my bug in the post. Please see my answer in the post.